# how to fix ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration problem?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, build.gradle

After I updated Android Studio to the new version, that is Android Studio Giraffe version
I get this error when running the app:

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
```

I checked the available questions and answers about this problem, but I could not solve my problem.

- Codes of `build.gradle` file in project level:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        gradle_version = '8.0.2'
        kotlin_version = '1.8.20'
        compose_bom_version = '2023.05.01'
        compose_version = '1.4.6'
        room_version = '2.5.2'
        hilt_version = '2.46.1'
        hilt_navigation_compose_version = '1.1.0-alpha01'
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-gradle-plugin:$hilt_version"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version "${gradle_version}" apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version "${gradle_version}" apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version "${kotlin_version}" apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

- Codes of `build.gradle` file in app level:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id "dagger.hilt.android.plugin"
}

android {
    namespace 'ro.alexmamo.roomjetpackcompose'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ro.alexmamo.roomjetpackcompose"
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    }
}

dependencies {
    //Compose
    implementation platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:$compose_bom_version")
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material"
    //Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"
    //Hilt
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$hilt_version"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler:$hilt_version"
    //Hilt Navigation Compose
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:$hilt_navigation_compose_version"
}
```

- Codes in `settings.gradle` file:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
rootProject.name = "RoomJetpackCompose"
include ':app'
```

- and this codes in `gradle.properties` file:

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.
# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.
# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html
# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:decoupled_projects
# org.gradle.parallel=true
# AndroidX package structure to make it clearer which packages are bundled with the
# Android operating system, and which are packaged with your app"s APK
# https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/androidx-rn
android.useAndroidX=true
# Kotlin code style for this project: "official" or "obsolete":
kotlin.code.style=official
# Enables namespacing of each library's R class so that its R class includes only the
# resources declared in the library itself and none from the library's dependencies,
# thereby reducing the size of the R class for that library
android.nonTransitiveRClass=true
```

For more explanation:
This project was imported from the following address in Android Studio:
https://github.com/alexmamo/RoomJetpackCompose/tree/master
But there is also this problem in some other projects.

Thank you very much in advance for your help.

- I checked the Toggle Offline Mode and that is off.
- Invalidate Caches not help to fix the problem.
- Clean project and sync gradle again not help also.